# Introduction to NServiceBus RetailDemo sample not able run due to Performance counter

Tags: nservicebus

**Using NServiceBus 6.4.3 sample ,  while running getting following error**

2018-02-11 13:35:18.008 INFO  DefaultFactory Logging to 'D:\MyProjects\NServiceB
us\NservicebusQuickStart\RetailDemo\Sales\bin\Debug\' with level Info
2018-02-11 13:35:18.320 INFO  NServiceBus.LicenseManager No valid license could
be found, falling back to trial license with start date '31-01-2018'

2018-02-11 13:35:18.633 INFO  NServiceBus.PerformanceMonitorUsersInstaller Skipp
ed adding user 'dbm\admin' to group 'Performance Monitor Users' because the user
 is already in group.

2018-02-11 13:35:18.695 INFO  NServiceBus.PerformanceCounterHelper NServiceBus p
erformance counter for '# of msgs pulled from the input queue /sec' is not set u
p correctly. To rectify this problem, consult the NServiceBus performance counte
rs documentation.

2018-02-11 13:35:18.711 INFO  NServiceBus.PerformanceCounterHelper NServiceBus p
erformance counter for '# of msgs successfully processed / sec' is not set up co
rrectly. To rectify this problem, consult the NServiceBus performance counters d
ocumentation.

2018-02-11 13:35:18.711 INFO  NServiceBus.PerformanceCounterHelper NServiceBus p
erformance counter for '# of msgs failures / sec' is not set up correctly. To re
ctify this problem, consult the NServiceBus performance counters documentation.
Press Enter to exit.

Any workaround.....

Answer (score 2):

Information messages that are logged do not require a workaround.
NServiceBus doesn't find a valid license file and starts a trial period.

For the performance counters, you would need to install performance counters. Documentation can be found [here](https://docs.particular.net/monitoring/metrics/performance-counters).

Comment: Hi Sean..I have installed NServiceBus.Metrics.PerformanceCounters.MsBuild 2.0.0.....but after compilation it showing following message : ClientUI.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ClientUI.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'D:\MyProjects\NServiceBus\NservicebusQuickStart\RetailDemo\ClientUI\bin\Debug\ClientUI.exe

Comment: What specific module are you trying to run @Krishnendu?

Comment: Hi Sean...Both  SLA and Critical Time counters ...I got stuck...Is that so typical to start with NServiceBus and make a POC...did they not verify before release there samples for new version...Is there any way to bypass the same...Please help

Comment: I am using windows 8.1 , VS 2017 Enterprise 15.2 , .Net Framework Ver 4.6..please let me know if you need any other information

Comment: Samples are verified. Could you let me know what module specifically you're trying to run? Which tutorial sample is that. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Sean...Here is the sample url  - https://docs.particular.net/tutorials/quickstart/  -- First of all I was not able to open it in VS 2017..showing project type is incompatible ...then I started to create the same...but got stuck with above issue...Thanks

Comment: I was able to download the tutorial and run it using VS2017 version 15.5.7. I'd recommend trying it on a different machine. The sample also required .NET framework 4.6.1. Worth verifying you've got that installed.